# Flash CS6: Text box only showing few characters

Tags: flash, button, text, actionscript

I am learning Flash and have run into a slight problem.

I have a text field and I want to change the text based on a random number, this is my text field:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwXK3.jpg

and this is my simple code:

```
function fl_GenerateRandomNumber(limit:Number):Number

{
    var randomNumber:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(limit+1));
    return randomNumber;
}

button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var getRandNum:Number = fl_GenerateRandomNumber(199);
    trace(getRandNum);
    Display_number_in_center.text = String(getRandNum);
}
```

running the above and clicking the button gives me random numbers because of the **TRACE** statement in the **OUTPUT**, but in the text field I only get displayed 1 or two characters and not the full random number.

For example if the random number is **123** then it displays **1**, if its **112** then it displays **11**.

Totally stumped as to whats wrong and where :(

Thanks!

Comment: your text box probably just isn't wide enough. make it bigger

Comment: See the picture: http://imgur.com/Uhm3wlV its huge!

Comment: are you running a trace to see what randomNumber is returning?

Comment: floor might be affecting it. maybe use round instead

Comment: That shouldnt, because if you look at where my trace statement is, it's displaying the number exactly from the variable,I am using that same variable to display in the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is a font embedding issue.

When using embedded fonts, Flash doesn't include all characters for the font by default. To save file size, it only includes the characters you specify in the "Font Embeding" panel, or that are edited into a text field, like "1" in the buttons in your example.

In other words, since "1" is the only character you have edited into a textfield, on your "+1" and "-1" buttons, "1" is the only numeral included when font glyphs are embedded in the swf, and the only numeral that can be displayed. Hence "if it's 123 then it displays 1, if it's 112 then it displays 11".

So go into the "Font Embeding" panel and make sure "Numerals" are included for the font used.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That was driving me nuts after searching the "text" properties for ages trying to find what was wrong :)